# Write image from raw image data received from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, cordova

I am trying to download file and save it on a device using Phonegap's File API.
But it always says "corrupted file". It works with text files though. I receive weird characters from this ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "xxxxxx"
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("xxxxxxx") }
}).done(function (data) {
requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onSuccess, onError);
    function onSuccess(fileSystem) {
        var directoryEntry = fileSystem.root;
        directoryEntry.getFile(name1, { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.createWriter(function (writer) {
                writer.write(data1);
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: How should that code work when you're missing a braket (**which i edited in now!** after your `done(function(data) {... ` you follow that directly with your `onSuccess` function and you're never closing your `done()`.

Comment: that was a mistake, i copied wrong.